# Google Maps API v3: disable drag during pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am playing around with the Google Maps and I came up with the question:

Is there a way to disable the drag without disabling the pinch zoom? I want to make those gestures completely exclusive one from the other, meaning, I want to make the user only be able to zoom or drag, but not simultaneously.

I tried using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
//JavaScript event listener (not a google maps event)
if (e.touches.length == 2) {
    //Two fingers, so it must be a pinch gesture
    map.setOptions({ draggable: false });
}
}, false);
```

and then added a listener for the 'idle' event in which I set the map to be draggable again.

The problem is that making the map "undraggable" disables the pinch functionality, which is not what I want to achieve. I have looked on the Google Maps API documentation but I cant find anything relevant to it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try creating a function that listens to pinch and zoom_changed events or drag events and inside that, write your desired behavior. The list of events are found in User [Interface Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).